# List lookup is slower than set lookup

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

I'm currently doing a project in which I have to check multiple times if a given 2D point is "legal", that is if it's within the boundaries of a grid and if it hasn't been visited before. The grid has a fixed `H x W` size, so I thought I could maybe store them not in a set, but a 2D lookup table. To my surprise, it's significantly slower than checking if it appears in a set, even though it's (in theory) an `O(logn)` operation, as opposed to `O(1)` with a simple array lookup.

First try:

```
class PointSet:
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        if h <= 0 or w <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Invalid size")
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.lookup = [[False for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)]
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, point):
        r, c = point
        self.lookup[r][c] = True
        self.size += 1

    def remove(self, point):
        r, c = point
        self.lookup[r][c] = False
        self.size -= 1

    def __contains__(self, point):
        r, c = point
        return 0 <= r < self.h and 0 <= c < self.w and self.lookup[r][c]

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.size != 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

# H, W = ...
# pointset = PointSet(H, W)
# if (3, 5) in pointset:
#   ...
```

Second try:

```
#  pointset = set()
#  if (3, 5) in pointset:
#    ...
```

Second code executes much faster. Why is that the case?

Comment: Both sets and lists have a `O(1)` "get item" complexity, so I think the difference here is that sets are built-ins (most likely implemented in C) whereas your custom `PointSet` is written in python and therefore slower.

Comment: @Rawing: That's what I was thinking as well, thought I might not have noticed something obvious that screws up the complexity. Thanks

Comment: I noticed that I increase the size of my set every time I call the `add()` method, even if the point had already been visited. It somehow still works in my code; hasn't changed the execution time at all though.

Comment: Please show the full code from which you've drawn your conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to consider that your implementation of `__contains__` method calls `__getitem__` **twice** (because you have a list of lists) with each having 0(1) complexity, and would evaluate two chained comparisons (`0 <= r < self.h` and `0 <= c < self.w`); in the worst case, all the expressions are evaluated since `and` will only short-circuit on the first `False`. There's an additional overhead coming from the iterable unpacking in the preceding line. There are also minor additions from the attribute lookups.

Membership lookup for sets is just plain 0(1), so I don't see how your code can possibly beat that.